# Can I enforce a method parameter that has a generic but in the method defined type?

Tags: java, generics, methods

I have a value class with generic type:

```
class TestValue<T> {
    TestValue(T value) {
    }
}
```

And a method that expects TestValue with a specific SomeObject type:

```
public void setValue(TestValue<SomeObject> value) { }
```

Is there a way to show a compiler error when calling this method with a value that is not of SomeObject type?

eg show a compiler error when calling this with Double instead of SomeObject

```
TestValue t = new TestValue(1d);
setValue(t);
```

^^ this should show an error

Comment: It should show an error if you don't use raw types: `TestValue<Double> t = new TestValue<>(1d);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/5133585

Comment: You can define `<T extends SomeObject>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IntelliJ the compiler actually finds these issues, but they are shown as warnings. You can edit the inspection settings and set Java | Compiler issues | Unchecked warning to error, then it is show as error.

[image]